# Running apache and cron in docker

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, alpine-linux

I understood there should be  only one process running on foreground in a docker container.  Is there any chance of running both apache and cron together in foreground? A quick search says there is something called supervisord to achieve this. But is there any other method using Entrypoint script or CMD?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:edge
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk   /repositories
RUN  apk add \
     bash \ 
     apache2 \
     php7-apache2 \
     php7 \
     curl \
     php7-mysqli \
     php7-pdo \
     php7-pdo_mysql

 RUN cp /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php
 RUN mkdir /startup
 COPY script.sh /startup
 RUN chmod 755 /startup/script.sh
 ENTRYPOINT ["/startup/script.sh"]
```

The content of script.sh is pasted below

```
#!/bin/bash
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
# start apache
httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

When the docker is run with this image only crond is running and most interestingly when I kill the cron then apache starts and running in the foreground.

I am using aws ecs ec2 to run the docker container using task definition and a service.

Answer (score 3):

Docker container is running while main process inside it is running. So if you want to run two services inside docker container, one of them has to be run in a background mode.

I suggest to get rid of `scrip.sh` at all and replace it just with one `CMD` layer:

```
CMD ( crond -f -l 8 & ) && httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:edge
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN  apk add \
     bash \ 
     apache2 \
     php7-apache2 \
     php7 \
     curl \
     php7-mysqli \
     php7-pdo \
     php7-pdo_mysql

RUN cp /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php
CMD ( crond -f -l 8 & ) && httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running crond -f, without telling bash to run it in the background, basically keeping bash waiting for crond to exit to continue running the script. There's two solutions for this:

1. Remove the -f flag (that flag causes crond to run in the foreground).
2. Add & at the end of the crond line, after -l 8 (I wouldn't recommend this).

Also, I'd start apache with exec:

```
exec httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Otherwise /startup/script.sh will remain running, while it's not doing anything useful anymore anyway. exec tells bash to replace the current process with the command to execute.

Comment: Great!!! that worked like a charm!!!  even though killing the crond is not stopping the container this will meet my requirement.

Comment: @friek I don't understand your "wouldn't recommend this" comment. Can you edit the answer to show what you do recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Found a different solution from another post:

```
# Add a command to base-image entrypoint script
RUN sed -i 's/^exec /service cron start\n\nexec /' /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground
```

(example starts from php:7.4-apache)

Which will get your cron process running inside the container along with apache2. On a related note, I got here investigating how to change permissions on files inside of a volume after the container starts, but since you have cron running now, just copy in a shell file that does whatever corrections you like and set it to run in cron every minute like this:

```
COPY permissionsfixes.sh /tmp/permfixes.sh
RUN (echo "* * * * * /tmp/permfixes.sh") | crontab
```